Modify/Alter Namespaced Unlocked Package data and metadata
What I am facing is that, I have an Unlocked Package without a namespace and I am able to alter/modify in that package, but in another package which is namespaced I am not being able to make any alterations except for labels/descriptions (non-metadata related stuff).

That's expected behavior with managed packages.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_configuring_packages.htm&type=5

Unlocked Packages can also have a namespace, however. It would probably be useful to mention that they should check what type of package they created.
